# Excel VBA: Delete sheet after exporting to PDF

Tags: excel, vba

I have written the following code tied to a command button to prompt the user to define a save path, export the active sheet to PDF and open it, then delete the sheet after it's been exported and activate a different sheet. The code works to completion but right at the end, I get a the following error:

> Run-time error '-2147221080 (800401a8)':
>
> Automation error

Below is my code. Any help would be immensely appreciated.

```
Private Sub ExceptionPrint_Click()

Sheet_Name = ActiveSheet.Name
PDF_Name = "Exception - " & ActiveSheet.Name & ".pdf"

Set File_Dialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
File_Dialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
File_Dialog.Title = "Select the Desired Location"
If File_Dialog.Show <> -1 Then
Exit Sub
End If

PDF_Name = File_Dialog.SelectedItems(1) & "\" & PDF_Name

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
Type:=xlTypePDF, _
Filename:=PDF_Name, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
OpenAfterPublish:=True

If Sheets("Data").Range("H12").Value = "W1" Then
    Sheets("Week 1").Activate
    Sheets("Data").Range("H12").Value = ""
Else
    Sheets("Week 1").Activate
    Sheets("Data").Range("H12").Value = ""
End If

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets(Sheet_Name).Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

I've tried everything I could think of, but I'm not that great with VBA to begin with.

Comment: I made a test workbook, even tried protecting a sheet but could not  reproduce the error. Are you certain the sheet names are correct "Data"/"Week 1"?

Comment: From what you've described (and from what I've replicated) you're getting that error because you're trying to delete the sheet that actually _contains the code_ (if, in the VBE, you look in the code module of the sheet _containing your button_, you will find the code there) - I think you should reorganise your file, to contain e.g. an index/control sheet, where you have a dropdown for the user to select the tab they want to export, and then the selected tab can be exported and deleted without issue (as the sheet containing the executed code will then still exist).

Comment: Also, you'll make your VBA experience less error prone if you [declare your variables](https://youtu.be/N1mADWqzWy4?t=479).

Comment: If you change `Sheets(Sheet_Name).Delete` to `If ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count <> 1 Then ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet_Name).Delete Else MsgBox "Cannot delete anymore sheets. Workbook has only one worksheet."`, does it still give an error?

Comment: @SpectralInstance That makes sense, thanks. I ended up handling it a different way so thank you everyone for your responses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just leaving a "Delete Sheet" button on the sheet in question rather than having it automatically delete. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the active sheet to a reference at the start and use that reference throughout the program. Also try to catch early any errors that the user might make.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub ExceptionPrint_Click()

    Dim wb As Workbook, wsPDF As Worksheet, PDF_Name As String
      
    ' validation
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsPDF = wb.ActiveSheet
    With wsPDF
         If .Name = "Week 1" Or .Name = "Data" Then
             MsgBox "Sheet " & wsPDF.Name & " must not be selected", vbCritical
             Exit Sub
         ElseIf WorksheetFunction.CountA(.UsedRange) = 0 Then
             MsgBox .Name & " is blank", vbCritical
             Exit Sub
         End If
    End With
    
    ' select folder
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Select the Desired Location"
        If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
        PDF_Name = .SelectedItems(1) & "\Exception - " & wsPDF.Name & ".pdf"
    End With

    ' print and delete
    wsPDF.ExportAsFixedFormat Filename:=PDF_Name, Type:=xlTypePDF, _
          IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
          OpenAfterPublish:=True
        
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wsPDF.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    ' finish
    With wb
        .Sheets("Week 1").Activate
        .Sheets("Data").Range("H12").Value = ""
    End With
    
End Sub
```